# R, time series, average, sequence

Tags: r, sequence, mean, zoo

Hey guys I have a zoo object of daily observations for 30 years that Looks something like this:

```
date        x
1971-11-01  145.234
1971-11-02  234.522
1971-11-03  423.32
1971-11-04  333.11
```

I would like to calculate means for the period November to April for the entire time series. So my desired result should look like this:

```
date              x
11/1971-04/1972   642.43
11/1972-04/1973   142.53
11/1973-04/1974   642.39
11/1974-04/1975   424.75
11/1975-04/1976   185.34
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Filter your data so you only have the ones from April to November, then group for year and apply the mean to each group.

Comment: I Need to put the November and December values of one year into the same Group as the Jan,Feb,Mar, and April values of the next year. That's my Problem and it is not adressed by your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates are truly daily such that November first appears every year, the following strategy will allow you to group the observations.

```
# drop observations outside of the window (May through October).
dfNew <- df[!grepl("^(0[56789]|10)", format(df$date, "%m")), ]

# build groups
dfNew$groups <- cumsum(c(TRUE, tail(grepl("11-01", format(dfNew$date, "%m-%d")), -1)))
```

The first line uses a logical vector based on a regular expression to drop months May through October. The second line uses a regular expression to return a logical vector indicating whether the observation is November first. I cut off the first element of the vector using `tail` and added TRUE, to make sure the that the group count begins with 1. `cumsum` is then used to create the group indicators.

At this point, you can use `aggregate`, for example, to get the group mean:

```
aggregate(x ~ groups, data=dfNew, FUN=mean)
  groups           x
1      1 -0.14947871
2      2 -0.02742739
3      3 -0.02296979
4      4  0.01939372
5      5 -0.01432937
6      6  0.10393297
7      7  0.06660049
8      8 -0.03955617
9      9 -0.06956639
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("1971-01-01"), as.Date("1979-01-01"), by="day"),
                 x=rnorm(2923))
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It Looks like it coul work but I can't figure out what you adress with the variable "temp"??

Comment: I've edited that part and added a reproducible example.